# Target child only if parent has a particular sibling

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have no control of the markup but here is how its rendered.

```
<div class="div1">

  <div class="div2">
    <p>Dont not select me</p>
  </div>

</div>


<div class="div1">
    <strong> 
    <p>Do not select me </p>
    </strong>
   <div class="div2">
    <p>Select me only with css </p>
   </div>
</div>
```

I want to target `p` tag in `div2` only if `div1` has a sibling with a `strong` around it.

Is that possible?

UPDATE: 
i was wrong.

Comment: If you ended up using p:nth-child(2), then either you're lying or your question doesn't reflect your actual markup, because p:nth-child(2) cannot possibly match anything in your question.

Comment: it actually works - you can test it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) `+`:

```css
.div1 strong+.div2 p {
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2">
    <p>Dont not select me</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="div1">
  <strong> 
    <p>Do not select me </p>
    </strong>
  <div class="div2">
    <p>Select me only with css </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Target a `p` that is a child of `.div2` that is a sibling of `strong`:

```css
strong ~ .div2 > p {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2">
    <p>Dont not select me</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="div1">
  <strong> 
    <p>Do not select me </p>
    </strong>
  <div class="div2">
    <p>Select me only with css </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the general sibling combinator `~`

```css
.div1 strong ~ .div2 p {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">

  <div class="div2">
    <p>Dont not select me</p>
  </div>

</div>


<div class="div1">
  <strong> 
    <p>Do not select me </p>
  </strong>
  <div class="div2">
    <p>Select me only with css </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use this to select it.

```
.div1 strong + .div2 > p
```

This is using adjacent sibling and sibling selectors
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp